# How do I display user profiles around my area using xcode while buiding an app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to access user profiles in my area for my app. Like accessing an image that a user uploads in my app. But I need to show all the images of all users in and around the area of the logged in user in my app. 
I need help with this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by continously uploading the current location of each user , and when a logged in one tries to see other profiles in your server according to a specifed region you set loop for all users that exists in this region and send their profies as the search result

Comment: Ok I'll try my best.I'll get the users location and try to tap into the users image and display it.

Comment: hey I'm having a problem with fetching the users that are closest or,  are at a particular distance(like 3 kms, or 2kms ) from the logged in user. How am I supposed to do this ?